# Attaching to existing object in a many to many relation with Entitiy Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a Rest API using Web API2 and EF6 Code first starting from the guide on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4
I'm basically doing the same thing having a many to many relationship and when i am creating an object, lets call it A, i include an array of B objects as the Bs variable in the post. They all get created as expected on the initial post, however when i add a second Object A which should link to one or more of the same B's as the first object A it instead of matching to the existing B's tries to create new B's but since there is a constraint on the name of the B this wont work. How do i ensure that it does not try to create a new object B every-time and instead link to an existing Object B if there is one?.

Here is the example in more detail.

I have two Models, lets call them A and B. They have a many to many relation

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100), Index("IDX_Name", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<B> Bs{ get; set; }
}
```

Model B

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100), Index("IDX_Name", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<B> As{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm not including the auto generated context.
and in the auto generated Controller scaffolding for the Web API POST method for Model A it looks like this

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(A))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostGame(A a)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.As.Add(a);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = a.Id }, a);

    }
```

All tables are created just fine and if i do the first post creating my first object A with the following json:

```
    {
    "Name": "FirstA",
    "Description": "FirstADesc",
    "Bs" : [{"Name":"FirstB"}]
    }
```

It works and both FirstA and FirstB is created.
If i then post a SecondA which is also linked to the FirstB obect

```
    {
    "Name": "SecondA",
    "Description": "SecondADesc",
    "Bs" : [{"Name":"SecondB"},{"Name":"FirstB"}]
    }
```

It will instead of finding the FirstB try to create it again. Which it due to the constraint.

My first guess was that i should use the ID:s instead in the second post. like:

```
    {
    "Name": "SecondA",
    "Description": "SecondADesc",
    "Bs" : [{"Id":"1"},{"Name":"FirstB"}]
    }
```

but this does not work either.

Is the only way of achieving this to replace the scaffolding code from the controller and check each object in Bs manually if it exist already?.

Basically its a "Tags to a post problem"...
I've looked into the Attached vs Detached Data subject and read articles on the matter without finding an answer that i can understand whether this can be done automatically with some proper annotations or if it has to be done "manually" in the controller.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not much response on this one,
Ended up looping and manually checking for an existing entry like below.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(A))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostGame(A a)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    foreach (var asd in a.Bs.ToList())
    {
    var t = db.Bs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == asd.Name);
      if (t != null)
      {
        a.Bs.Remove(asd);
        a.Bs.Add(t);
      }
    }
    db.As.Add(a);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = a.Id }, a);

}
```

Cant help to feel that there has to be a better way then this though.